# Re-structure the split labels at the end of each leaf in rpart

Tags: plot, character, rpart, party

I am currently working with **rpart.plot()** to plot a decision tree (like the one attached in the picture).

My concern is whether I can split the line, containing the levels of the decision choice below each leaf, in two lines?
In this way the information will be contained in a more reduced space and information will be more visual when I include it in the paper.

One possibility I have tried is to reduce the names forming the levels, but still it does not reduce the dimensionality that much.

In the following figure I represent what I am looking for.

[image]

Any clue?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hidden in the
[vignette for rpart.plot](http://www.milbo.org/doc/prp.pdf)
there is an example for this.

In that vignette, Section 6.1 **Customizing the split labels** explains how to break up long labels.

It gives example code and plots.
(The example there uses `prp`, but you can use `prp` or `rpart.plot`.)